# Why there is no lottie spec?

Tags: javascript, json, animation, lottie

I tried to look at the json below with https://lottiefiles.com/tools/json-editor I can't even understand what this simple animation does by reading the json file :

```
{"v":"5.5.7","meta":{"g":"LottieFiles AE 0.1.20","a":"","k":"","d":"","tc":""},"fr":60,"ip":0,"op":300,"w":1000,"h":1080,"nm":"Comp 1","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"Shape Layer 1","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"t":0,"s":[960,540,0],"to":[129.301,0.393,0],"ti":[-129.301,-0.393,0]},{"t":180,"s":[1735.808,542.358,0]}],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ty":"rc","d":1,"s":{"a":0,"k":[485.764,165.065],"ix":2},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"nm":"Rectangle Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Rect","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.839215446921,0,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":2,"ix":5},"lc":1,"lj":1,"ml":4,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"fl","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.980391917509,0,1],"ix":4},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":5},"r":1,"bm":0,"nm":"Fill 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[-481.31,110.83],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Rectangle 1","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":300,"st":0,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are lottie schema descriptions available for reference, and the one maintained by the original creator is available at:

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/tree/master/docs/json

Answer (score 1):

There are a few resources available online for studying the Lottie format.

The most easily digestible is the [lottie-docs project](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-docs), which is by the same person who did the python-lottie package (Matt Basaglia).

- [TypeScript definition](https://github.com/marcusstenbeck/lottie-types)
- [Bodymovin JSON docs](https://github.com/bodymovin/bodymovin/tree/master/docs/json)
- [python-lottie docs](https://mattbas.gitlab.io/python-lottie/group__Lottie.html#details)
- [Matt Basaglia’s lottie-docs](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-docs)
- [Lottie Animation Community repos](https://github.com/lottie-animation-community/)